# JPA criteria api order by query for @EmbeddedId

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have 2 classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DRCOMMENTS" ,schema = "XXX")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Drcomments.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Drcomments d"),
public class Drcomments implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId    
protected DrcommentsPK drcommentsPK;

@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "SDESC")
private String commentSecondaryCodeDescription;
}


@Embeddable
public class DrcommentsPK implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "CODE")
private Short commentPrimaryCode;

@NotNull   
@Column(name = "SCODE" , length=5)
private Short commentSecondaryCode;
}
```

I'm trying to create a query with a dynamic order by and a parameter, for example:
I want to select all Drcomments records when DrcommentsPK.commentPrimaryCode equels 1, and the order by will be by DrcommentsPK.commentSecondaryCode.  this is what i tried:

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Drcomments> q = cb.createQuery(Drcomments.class);
    Root<Drcomments> c = q.from(Drcomments.class);

    q.select(c);
    q.where(cb.equal(c.get("drcommentsPK").get("commentPrimaryCode"), 1));

    Path<Drcomments> valuePath = c.get("drcommentsPK").get("commentSecondaryCode"); 
    Order[] orders; 
    if(sord.equals("desc"))
    {  
    orders = new Order[] {cb.desc(valuePath)};
    } 
    else
    {  
    orders = new Order[] {cb.asc(valuePath)};
    } 
    q.orderBy(orders);

    query = em.createQuery(q);                
    query.setFirstResult(start);
    query.setMaxResults(start + limit);   

    results = query.getResultList();
```

The problem is that the resultlist I get is not sorted in the commentSecondaryCode desc order..

am I doing somthing wrong?  how can this be done? how to create a query that will be ordered by a field inside the emeddable class?

**UPDATE:**
this is the generated sql I get:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT EL_TEMP.*, ROWNUMBER() OVER() AS EL_ROWNM FROM 
(SELECT CMSSDESC AS a1, CMSSCODE AS a4, CMSPCODE AS a5 FROM DRCOMMENTS
 WHERE (CMSPCODE = 1) ORDER BY CMSSCODE DESC, CMSPCODE DESC)
 AS EL_TEMP) 
 AS EL_TEMP2 WHERE EL_ROWNM <= 50) 
 AS EL_TEMP3 WHERE EL_ROWNM > 0
```

when I run this code it wont return the records in the CMSSCODE desc order..
(beacuse the order by should be in the outer select..)
do I need to change somthing in the `query.setFirstResult()` and `query.setMaxResults()` ?
I how do I add it to the end in the criteria query, so it will be in the last select?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like? You might find hits there.

Comment: @Rasmus Franke: how can I see the generated SQL string value?

Comment: It's a vendor dependant configuration in your persistence.xml. For example, with hibernate just add `<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>` to your persistence xml.

Comment: @Rasmus Franke: I'm using eclipseLink, but I got the generated SQL string, and I've updated my question.. thank's.

Comment: The SQL is a bit weird, so many subselects? Does it work if you skip the first/max result parts?

Comment: @Rasmus Franke: It works greate if I delete the `query.setFirstResult()` and `query.setMaxResults()` parts.. but I need them so it's not an option. I tested the sql, and the problem is in the sql even with one subselect. when there is `select from select` and in the inner select there is order by, the result won't be sorted. so I think I need to add the order by after the set first/max, Is this possible? thank's.

Comment: Looking at your generated SQL, I think that it should till return the rows in order. SELECT * FROM (x) won't reorder elements, so the ordering in the inner query will remain in the outside SELECTs. Your generated SQL looks similar the the official example at http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Pagination . Perhaps your problem lies elsewhere? Are you sure that the objects are truly not sorted?

Comment: @Rasmus Franke: I found that inorder to get the result sorted I need to add `order by filed_name desc` into the `over()`. can I do that with my current CriteriaQuery? how can this be added to the query ? thank's again.

Comment: What is `over()`? Do you just want to sort by another field?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine and standard compliant. If you are sure it doesn't work, then there must be bug in implementation or some odd stuff in those parts of code that is not shown. For example, check that value of `sord` is exactly `"desc"` (case sensitive), because otherwise you will fall to use ascending order.

I tried it with Hibernate 3.6.8.Final and EclipseLink (2.3.2). With both of them it works as expected - `ORDER BY SCODE [ASC/DESC]` is part of the executed SQL query.

Comment: I checked the `sord` value , and it's o.k.. but I've updated my question with the generated sql string. thank's.

Comment: Query seems to be correct. Can you give example of actual and expected result?

Comment: I found that inorder to get the result sorted I need to add order by filed_name desc into the over(). can I do that with my current CriteriaQuery? how can this be added to the query ? thank's again.